# Boolean algebra - Maxterms

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have a boolean expression and I need to get to the canonical forms of it (sum of minterms and product of maxterms).

In order to get an expression for the first canonical form, I need to multiply every term by (x + ~x), where x is the missing variable. Is there a similar algorithm to get to the second canonical form?

Answer (score 1):

Look here, page 7:
[sop-pos-conversion](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse370/10wi/pdfs/lectures/04-CanonicalForms.pdf)

You can also derive them separately from the truth table.  It might be easier than converting from one to the other, depending on how large the expression is.